# how to handle error thrown by rxjs post

Tags: rxjs6

From my backend service, I am sending a `post` message

```
return this.http.post(/*this.API_URL +*/this.NEW_QUESTION_URL,body,httpOptions)
      .map(response => { 
          return result; //map isn't required
        }

      })
      .catch(this.handleError); //error handler if Observable fails
```

In `handleError`, I am throwing an error

```
private handleError (error: HttpErrorResponse) {
console.error('WebToBackendInterfaceService::handleError', error);//I SEE THIS PRINT
        let result:ServerResponseAPI = {result:"error", "additional-info":error.message};
    return throwError(result);     
  }
```

My question - I suppose `throwError` returns an `Observable`. How and where do I subscribe to this Observable so that I can handle the error?

I suppose the `Observable` returned by `post` is different from the one from `throwError`. I have subscribed to the `Observable` of `post` already.

I also have a custom interceptor.

```
return next.handle(cloned)
 .pipe(tap((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => { 
        console.log("got an event",ev);
        if (ev.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          console.log('event of type Http response');
        }  else if (ev.type === HttpEventType.Sent) {
          console.log(" event of type httpsent");
        } else if(ev.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress){
          console.log("event of type download progress");
        } else if (ev.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          console.log("event of type upload progress");
        } else if (ev.type === HttpEventType.User) {
          console.log("event of type user progress");
        }else if (ev.type === HttpEventType.ResponseHeader) {
          console.log("event of type response header")
        } else {
          console.log("don't know type",ev.type);
        }
      })
      ,catchError(errorResponse => {
          console.log("caught error from server",errorResponse) //I SEE THIS PRINT
          return observableThrowError(errorResponse);
      }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ah! basic Rxjs stuff I reckon. While subscribing to an observable, I can provide handlers for data, error and complete. I had provided handler only for data.

```
let subscription = this.dataService.addData(this.data)
    .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("got data ", data)
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log("got error from the Observable: ", error)
        },
        () => {
            console.log("observable completed")
        });
```